# CentOS Format USB without partition

Tags: centos, usb-drive, removable-storage

I have a CentOS 5 server that is using an external HDD for crontab backups.

The crontab uses several scripts when working with the HDD which is /dev/sdb
but the HDD is getting old now and it's time to replace it.

I've inserted the replacement HDD which is now /dev/sdc and it has a
partition /dev/sdc1

I tried to format it using

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Which worked but now when I plug it into the old HDDs port the scripts
don't work because the drive is /dev/sdb1 and not /dev/sdb

Is it possible to format an external HDD to be /dev/sdb instead of
/dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1 and what is the recommended linux format

Comment: Your problem is unclear.  I think it has to do with the script which you're not showing us or the way you call it.  How does it know it's suppose to use `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc`, or `/dev/sdc1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do not need a partition, you can format the whole disk, eg in your example make sure `/dev/sdc1` is not mounted then do:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc
```

You may get a warning that there is a partition table. After the format you need to make sure the kernel knows there is no partition, so use

```
partprobe /dev/sdc
```

and check that `/dev/sdc1` no longer exists.  You can now mount `/dev/sdc`.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need, I will try it out now

Comment: on a side note though, I have always used partitions except for this rare case. Are there any drawbacks to not creating a partition?

Comment: I dont know of anything major. It is harder to give a label to a filesystem than to a partition, for identification. For a usb device it is fairly common not to partition.

Comment: This worked perfectly I can mount the /dev/sdc is it possible to delete the existing /dev/sdc1 partition though?

Comment: You should no longer have a `/dev/sdc1` device, as the kernel will remove it when it is told to reread the disk partitioning. If it still exists, you should probably unmount `sdc`, `sync`, and remove the usb device, then plug it in again. I dont think it matters, but it would be cleaner for `sdc1` not to appear.

Comment: Unplugging it and plugging it back in again did seem to fix it, thanks a bunch for your help